# TestNg Parallel execution result shows less pass percentage compare to Normal Execution

Tags: selenium, testng

I am running my selenium test framework using testng.xml file. When I run the tests in the testng.xml parallelly(different browsers) , the pass percentage is very less,i.e 80% but when I run the testng.xml , the pass percent is above 95. Could some one tell me why it could be so?

Comment: Probably because of [Race Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) - I'm voting to close this question as it's too broad.

Comment: @Jim - the information you have provided is very little. Its not sufficient to debug to see what is the problem. So here are some questions that you could add answers to (by editing your question).
1. Is it always the same tests that fail ?
2. What is the nature of failures ? Are they genuine application failures (or) are they related to element not being found etc., which you feel is false alarms.
3. How does your browser instantiation look like ? Can you show the code ?

Comment: Answering your questions 1. Is it always the same tests that fail ? - no, it isn't the same test that fails  2. What is the nature of failures ? - Are they genuine application failures (or) are they related to element not being found etc., which you feel is false alarms. - All are related to element not found exception , when running in normal mode , no errors occur 3. How does your browser instantiation look like ? Can you show the code ? - I use before method to instantiate my driver. Currently use Firefox and Chrome. I call the browser infrmation from Testng xml as parameter to@beforemethod

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan please let me know if you need more info

Comment: @Jim - That still doesn't tell a lot in terms of what could be causing failures. You would need to share some samples which shows how your browser instantiation looks like, how does a test method look like (along with all supporting java classes that the test method uses ). Since you are saying that its a element not found exception there can be two reasons.. 1. Your application by itself is having performance issues due to which concurrent accesses cause it to work slowly. For fixing that you may have to use explicit waits (WebDriverWait).

Comment: 2. You are perhaps searching for an element in the wrong browser instance (this can happen when your webdriver context gets mixed up for your tests and your tests end up using the wrong webdriver instance to query the page. 
In either case, without seeing code, not much can be said.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan , I have posted my driver instantiation in the following link, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/468423864647f7165861a861e89d8dae#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: @Jim - The code is NOT complete. Please understand that this only makes it more difficult to debug. For e.g., in the code that you posted where is the WebDriver data member defined. If you are looking at your issue being resolved, you would need to show the complete code. Sharing things in bits and pieces is NOT helping here! I have a hunch that your test code is what is causing the failure, but for me to confirm on that hunch I would need to see something more concrete !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make the below changes in your code and after that your concurrency related issues should go away.

Within your `BrowserHandler`:

- Within `getDriver(String browsername)` add `WebDriver driver = null` as the first line (We are declaring WebDriver to be a local variable now)
- Remove the data member `protected  WebDriver driver=null;` and instead include a thread local variant : `private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>()`;
- Add a new method such as below :

`public static WebDriver getDriver() {
    return driver.get();
}`

`public static void setDriver(WebDriver localDriver) {
    driver.set(localDriver);
}`

Within your `BaseClass` :

- In the method `launch_App()` change `getDriver(browsername);` to `setDriver(getDriver(browsername));`
- In the method `afterMethod(ITestResult result)` change `driver.quit();` to `getDriver().quit()`.
- In the method `afterMethod(ITestResult result)` add an extra line `setDriver(null);` after the statement `getDriver().quit();`

Now through out your test code, whenever you need to access the webdriver you should be using `getDriver()` [ I am assuming that all your test classes are going to extend `BaseClass` (which again extends `BrowserHandler`)]

To learn more about ThreadLocal please refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

Comment: I also use page factory. how do I pass driver reference in page factory class, i.e in the constructor created in the page factory class.

Comment: As long as you are calling PageFactory.initElements() from within a @Test method, you can still call getDriver() to gain access to it.

Comment: Like I said, you need to ensure that all the calls are happening within a Test method because BeforeMethod > Test > AfterMethod would be executed in the same thread and that's how you will be able to get access to webdriver that is set in the current thread context.

Also if my answer helps you, please accept it.

Comment: Successfully implemented the same into the framework